# why Flash global interrupt handler not defined in stm32 startup code?

Tags: embedded, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to implement [stm32f407](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) drivers from bare-metal, I didn't have any problem until I came to interrupt the handler for flash memory operations.

clearly on page `372` in the reference manual (Vector table for STM32F405xx/07xx and STM32F415xx/17xx), it shows that the address of the flash interrupt handler is at `0x0000 0050`. but when I opened the startup code provided by stm32, I found this:

```
  .word RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler                     /* RTC Wakeup interrupt through the EXTI line                         */
  .word 0                                       /* Reserved                                                           */
  .word RCC_IRQHandler                          /* RCC global interrupt
```

so for some reason, the address for the flash interrupt handler function is reserved in the startup code, but the reference manual says:

[image]

so I really don't understand why **ST** decided to reserve this address in its startup code?

Comment: What does ST say? You asked them, didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a recent version of CubeIDE etc? I just made a project (in version 1.12.0 of STM32CubeIDE) and I see this in `startup_stm32f407vetx.s`:

```asm
  .word     RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler     /* RTC Wakeup through the EXTI line */
  .word     FLASH_IRQHandler        /* FLASH                        */
  .word     RCC_IRQHandler          /* RCC                          */
```

Comment: yes indeed, Version: 1.13.0. it's just so weird they changed in one minor version release

Comment: All this stuff is on github somewhere. You could look at the commit history, and raise an issue if appropriate.